# Combine two files in linux without repetition

Tags: c, linux, shell, awk

I have two files file1 and file2

Contents of file1 is

```
Hello
  how
are you
when can i meet you
film??
```

Contents of file2 is

```
Hello 
how 
are you
darling
when can i meet you
```

I want to generate a file which is a combination of two file like

```
Hello
how
are you
darling
when can i meet you
film??
```

Note: Space in the second line of `file1` should be ignored in the final file
is there any inbuilt function in C or Linux to do the above following job or can a script be written to do this?

Comment: If such a function exists I've certainly never seen it. You'll likely have to write one yourself.

Comment: You can use `fgets` = read lines and `strcmp` = compare string .

Comment: If you want to not use some commands under linux you can make a simple program in C that can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"") } !a[$0]++' file2 file1
```

Results:

```
Hello
how
are you
darling
when can i meet you
film??
```

---

*EDIT:*

The problem with:

```
awk '{ $1=$1 } !a[$0]++' file2 file1
```

Is that, although it works well for this simple example, it will treat similar lines as the same thing because it not only removes leading and lagging whitespace, but it will also remove extra whitespace *between* fields. For example, if `file1` contains:

```
Hello
  how
are you
when  can i meet you
film??
```

Both the:

```
when can i meet you
```

and:

```
when  can i meet you
```

lines would be treated as the same thing. This may be the desired result, but based on your question, I think it's best to simply strip leading and lagging whitespace as per the first command. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

Easy job for `awk`:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1}!u[$0]++' file2 file1
Hello
how
are you
darling
when can i meet you
film??
```

---

Or if you don't care about the order of the output:

```
$ sed 's/^\s*//' file1 file2 | sort -u 
are you
darling
film??
Hello
how
when can i meet you
```

Comment: "are you you", "can i meet you can i meet you" in output?

Comment: Damn, `join` almost did the trick, changed for `awk` solution.

Comment: does your awk line really give that output? I think it will process and print all lines of file1 and then file2. so the order was not kept. If you give parameter file2 file1, then it will give that ouput. however if the input files were slightly changed, the order could be wrong. Personally I think the rule was not clearly defined when two lines from two files are different, so it is hard to give a precise solution.

Comment: [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14233788/5) changed quite a bit. Did you see something you liked? I mean that in the nicest possible way of course. I've added an explanation as to why `$1=$1` may not be what the OP is looking for. Please see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14234889/751863).

Comment: @steve yes I was over thinking, I got a nudge from somewhere `;)`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply several standard filters:

```
cat file1 file2 | perl -pe 's/^\s+//' | sort | uniq
```

- `cat` is used to concatenate all the required files,
- `perl` is udes to remove all initial whote space,
- `sort` sorts all lines,
- and `uniq` removes the duplicate lines.

Comment: @Kent: There seemed to me there were no constraints on the order of lines in the output, but the task was not well specified.

Comment: @anumi the output was specified by the OP.

Comment: @sudo_O: Well, the "like" word induces some liberty... In any case, I agree that my solution does not maintain the order.

Comment: @sudo_O: Wht i have given is just a example file, i have to files running to many lines, i need to do some thing very similar as above